# Why unable to Clear the SetInterval in javascript ? is this approach is wrong?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-timer, jquery-timing

In one of my app, angular based application have written the user session time put if user gets idle for 10 minutes , gets the warning pop up in 5th minute  and after 10 minutes , needs to logout.

This below code is working properly for the application.
In one module have to clear the setinterval, i am not able to clear it by using 
  `**clearInterval(idleCheck);**` .so something went wrong in below code.

angular run block have implemented user navigated between states, extend the time for 10 minutes.

```
myApp.run(function ($rootScope $interval, $timeout, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, $rootScope, $state, $location) {   

       lastDigestRun = Date.now();

       var m = lastDigestRun + 10 * 60 * 1000;      

        idleCheck = setInterval(function () {

              var now = Date.now();


                if (now - lastDigestRun > 5 * 60 * 1000) {
                    // show the pop up , the pop have continue to extend the time session if proceed        
                }
                if (now - lastDigestRun > 10 * 60 * 1000) {
                    // LOgout functionality
                }
            }
        }, 60 * 1000);


    });
});
```

And if user have some server request means have extend the time in this block to add the time again.

I have to clear the session,if url is like this; have try to clear its not clearing.

```
    if (url == 'stopsession') {               
                  clearInterval(idleCheck);

              }


var configFunction = function ($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider,$scope) {
   var interceptor = function ($q, $rootScope, $timeout, $location) {
      return {
          request: function (config) {
          //  consider this module reuest come here
              if (url == 'stopsessionurl') {               
                  clearInterval(idleCheck);

              }
```

else {

```
                  lastDigestRun = Date.now();
                  var m = lastDigestRun +  10 * 60 * 1000;
                   idleCheck = setInterval(function () {

                          var now = Date.now();

                          if (now - lastDigestRun > 5 * 60 * 1000) {
                              // show pop up  to extend the time if click continue another 10 minutes gets added
                          }
                          if (now - lastDigestRun > 10 * 60 * 1000) {
                            // logout functionality
                          }

                  }, 60 * 1000);
                  return config;
              }
          },
            requestError: function (config) {            
                return config;
            },

            response: function (response) {

            },
            responseError: function (rejection) {


            }
        }
    };

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
    };
```

So In one module have to stop the setInterval.But ClearInterval is not stopping.

This is full piece of code.

```
var idleCheck;

var myApp = angular.module('myApp','ui.router');
myApp.run(function ($rootScope $interval, $timeout, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, $rootScope, $state, $location) {   

       lastDigestRun = Date.now();

       var m = lastDigestRun + 10 * 60 * 1000;      

        idleCheck = setInterval(function () {

              var now = Date.now();


                if (now - lastDigestRun > 5 * 60 * 1000) {
                    // show the pop up , the pop have continue to extend the time session.

                }
                if (now - lastDigestRun > 10 * 60 * 1000) {
                    // LOgout functionality
                }
            }
        }, 60 * 1000);


    });
});

var configFunction = function ($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider,$scope) {
   var interceptor = function ($q, $rootScope, $timeout, $location) {
      return {
          request: function (config) {

              if (url == 'stopsession') {               
                  clearInterval(idleCheck);

              }
              else {

                  lastDigestRun = Date.now();
                  var m = lastDigestRun + 10 * 60 * 1000;
                   idleCheck = setInterval(function () {

                          var now = Date.now();

                          if (now - lastDigestRun > 5 * 60 * 1000) {
                              // show pop up  to extend the time if click continue another 10 minutes gets added
                          }
                          if (now - lastDigestRun > 10 * 60 * 1000) {
                            // logout functionality
                          }

                  }, 60 * 1000);
                  return config;
              }
          },
            requestError: function (config) {            
                return config;
            },

            response: function (response) {

            },
            responseError: function (rejection) {


            }
        }
    };

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
    };
```

Problems:

But Unable to clear the Interval.

if i am using $interval , timing is not working properly  and unable to clear by using $interval.cancel
Github: Demo :https://github.com/MohamedSahir/UserSession

Steps: go through video get more about issue:
Demo  Video :http://recordit.co/xHkJeUSdp1
Demo plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/UkVUvFWIQKYD6SUumNv4?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

When working with AngularJS you should use the [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service.

In your case it would go like this (repeat the same for every interval you need to create):

```
//... set interval
        idleCheck = $interval(function () {

              //... your code (omitted)

        }, 60 * 1000);
//...

//...clear interval
       $interval.cancel(idleCheck);
//...
```

Comment: if i use $interval means for the firsttime ,the calculation is working fine ,when i extend the time again , for the calculation is wrong, in middle of the time its logout , if i use setInterval the time manner is working properly , but only problem is with cleartimeout. if you need create an plunker demo after sometime.

Comment: @MohamedSahir, please, could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), maybe a plunker or a jsfiddle with the minimal required code, so I can reproduce your exact problem???

Comment: Demo recorded video : http://recordit.co/xHkJeUSdp1 Have created github here : https://github.com/MohamedSahir/UserSession ,Plunker Here : https://plnkr.co/edit/3ywUgI9362UUatExZ4FM?p=preview Let me help if you found something

Answer (score 0):

Don't use setInterval in angular.

AngularJS has a very nice $interval wrapper for setInterval which provides a promise API.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

PS: you are injecting the same but you are not using it.

Comment: in the beginning i have  used $interval it shows unexpected behaviour so i have used setInterval its working fine with local variable  clearInterval is the problem if you interest pls look through here  something wrong in above code , if i used idlecheck as local variable ,working as expected but  unable to clear the interval thttps://github.com/MohamedSahir/UserSession